# How can I upload single file to multiple path on aws s3 using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How can I upload single file to multiple path on aws-s3 using nodeJS?
Problem: I have 1 images file: images.jpg. And now, I want to upload this file to aws-s3 with different path.

Comment: Do you have any code to support this question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: If it is just a generic question, I would say use the aws-sdk. There are tons of snippets out there. [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploading file to different directory in s3, Give your accesskeyid and secretaccesskey,

```
const fs = require('fs'),
    AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
    {promisify} = require('util')



const uploadFile =async (file_path, folder) => {
    try {
        var s3 = new AWS.S3({
            accessKeyId: '',
            secretAccessKey: ''
        });

        //reading the file and converting it into buffer
        const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile).bind(fs);
        const data =await readFile(file_path)
        if (!data) throw "reading file failed";
        const params = {
            Bucket: 'testbucketnayan', // bucket name
            Key: `${folder}/file.js`,
            Body: data.toString()
        };
        const upload =  promisify(s3.upload).bind(s3);
        const up_data  = await upload(params)
        if (!up_data) throw "Upload failed"
        console.log(up_data)
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

The upload location is having the directory names. Where the file will get uploaded. looping through the array and uploading the file, you can use Promise.all, it will increase the performance.

```
const upload_location = ['abc', 'def'];
(async () => {
    for (var folder of upload_location) 
        await uploadFile('resposetwi.js', folder);
})()
```

Please ask your question with the code you tried, it makes it easier to understand where is the issue.